# 502 Bad gateway - PHP 7, Nginx, Centos

Tags: php, nginx, centos

I am trying to configure `CentOS 7.3`, `Nginx` and `PHP 7.3`, but I am getting:

> 502 Bad Gateway
>   nginx/1.10.3

This is site.com.conf:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name server IP;
root /var/www/site.com/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    include fastcgi_params;    
    }
}
```

If I upload static HTML to the public directory, I can see it, but if I try to load PHP files, i see that error.
I have `/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change `listen.owner` and `listen.groups` in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` to `nginx`:

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
```

Then restart with `service php-fpm restart`.
You can check for errors with: `systemctl status php-fpm.service`.